# Password protected iOS app on screen lock

Tags: ios, security, uiwindow

I am trying to password protect an iOS app by having a passcode screen (similar to the lock screen) pop up every time the app has been in the background. I've put the required code in `AppDelegate`'s `applicationWillEnterForeground:` and that part is OK. However, the problem is how to present this passcode screen. I tried to present a `UIViewController` modally from the root VC, but this creates problems if other modal VC are already present. My second option was to create a new `UIWindow` and make the passcode VC the `rootViewController`. This works, but I am not sure if this is best practice or if there are any better solutions. What I am looking for in the end is a solution similar to the one used in the Dropbox app.

So, my question clean and straight: Are there any security implications or bad practices by creating another `UIWindow` on top of the main window in order to show a passcode screen? And are there other suggestions on how to password protect an app like Dropbox do it?

Also, here is the code I am currently using:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    if (self.loggedInViewController && !lockVC) { //Verify that the application is actually logged in, and that no passcode is being shown
        lockVC = [[CWIXLoggedInLockedVC alloc] init];       //Create a new passcord VC
        passcodeWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; //Create passcode Window
        passcodeWindow.rootViewController = lockVC;         //Set passcode VC as root VC
        passcodeWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;    //Make sure the passcode is the foremost in the app
        [passcodeWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add the `CWIXLoggedInLockedVC` instance `view` as a subview to the app window. This means that no matter how many viewcontroller are presented you add view will always be on top.

Comment: just create a view as property in appdelegate class and whenever the returns to foreground call that view and if the passcode matches remove it....

Comment: Thank you, it works terrific. Sometimes I overcomplicate things ... Add it as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted :-)